# How can I get and send the selected date from my datepicker to the controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to do an event that would get the selected date and send it to a controller.  I have two javascripts on the page.  One at the top that loads a popup window and displays a partial view.  In the partial view I have a datepicker.

At the bottom of the page I put a separate javascript to call the get the selected date from inside the popup window  and send it to my controller.

Here’s the script that is at the top of my page.  This works ok for loading the popup window.

Markup code here…….

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {


        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm.dd.yy' });
        var dpkr = $(".datepicker");
        $("#dropdownselected1").val($("#categories").val());
        var selectedDate = dpkr.datepicker('getDate');



    });


    $(function () {


        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,

            title: "My Schedule",
            resizable: false,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('.modal').click(function () {
            $('#my-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;

             }); 

         });

     });
 </script>
```

Markup code here…….

At the bottom I tried this and it it does not send the selected date to the controller:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   var dpkr = $('datepicker');
   var sltdDate = dpkr.datepicker('getDate');
   $(function(){


  var selectedDate = { date: sltdDate };

    $.ajax({
   type:"GET ",
   url:"/Schedule/GetSchedule",
   data: selectedDate,
   datatype:"html",
     sucess:function(data){
   $('#result').html(data);
   }
   });


      });
     </script>
```

How can I get and send the selected date from my datepicker to the controller?

EDIT: The GetSchedule action.

```
 public ActionResult GetSchedule(string date)
    {   var viewModel = new ScheduleData();
    viewModel.Courses = db.Courses;
    viewModel.Enrollments = from s in db.Enrollments where s.InstructorId == 7 && s.classDays == "Monday" select s;




        return PartialView(viewModel);

    }

 }
```

Comment: Show us your `GetSchedule` action.

Comment: Are there any errors on the debug console?

Comment: try getting the value like $(".datepicker").val()

Comment: Also, `$(document).ready(function() { $(function() { }); });` is redundant. Use _one_ `$(document).ready(function() {});` or `$(function() {});`. See [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I've added the GetSchedule action to the end of the original post.  The action gets called but the parameter is null.

Comment: Seems to break in the console at:  }(jQuery, window, document, undefined));  Not experienced enough to interpret whether this has to do with not sending data to the controller.  I've removed the (document).

Comment: 1) Verify the date from the datepicker control i.e. `console.log(sltDate)` 2) Check the request headers for `/Schedule/GetSchedule` in the network monitor for your debug console. This will verify that the client-side code is really sending the expected date. 3) Fix the redundant "document ready" nesting. You only need to declare it once. 4) Your AJAX call is not within an (button) event handler so it will fire immediately after the page loads -- your user never gets an opportunity to specify a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the code block and got it to work like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datep").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonText: "Select Date", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-2:+2", showOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
        var sltdDate = { selectedDate: date};
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
            data: sltdDate,
            datatype: "html",
            sucess: function (data) {

            }
        });

       }


       });
         $("#datep").attr("placeHolder", "mm/dd/yyy").datatepicker();



    });     
 </script>
```